# Connecting SQL to php or java

Tags: java, php, oracle

Hello everyone I’ve been struggling a bit with connecting a oracle sql database to java and/or php. (I’ve attempted to use it with either language and failed). The problem is that the table/database is stored on my schools specific server and virtual machine(which doesnt have a IDE for java or php)and I’ve been trying to connect the table from my own local network and I am unable to connect the table to java and or php. I’ve had previous assignments where I’ve done similar assigments with ease becasue the tables/database and IDE were on the same server. Does anyone have any suggestions  on how I can connect the database to php and/or java please I’ve been trying constanly to connect for weeks?Please help thanks

Comment: You need to make the host reachable, port open, mysql listening on the accessible network interface and that the mysql user has rights for external connections etc, need more details on what you mean by own local network :/

Comment: First, I think you may ask your professor or the people in charge of the server in your school for assistance on how to connect. Second, it seems you have access to the server of some way _(maybe `ssh`, or direct access from a lab)_, you really don't need any IDE on the server, you may just write the code using any simple text editor, or in reality you can just write the code on the IDE on your personal computer and copy the files _(source code for php, or compiled jar for java)_ to the server and execute them there.

Answer (score -1):

```
   //this is a connection with java and sql server, but if you need change to oracle, you 
   //have that change the driver too.

 import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class Dao {   

     Connection cn;

            public void Conectar() throws Exception {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=NameDB;user=user;password=user");
                    if (cn != null) {
                        System.out.println("conected");
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }

            public void Cerrar() throws Exception {
                try {
                    if (cn != null) {
                        if (cn.isClosed() == false) {
                            cn.close();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }

            public Connection getCn() {
                return cn;
            }

            public void setCn(Connection cn) {
                this.cn = cn;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                Dao dao = new Dao();
                dao.Conectar();
            }
    }
```